# Call setter when any property of a class changes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Given a class like below:

```
public class LoginInfo
{
    public int UserId;
    public string Username;
}
```

and another class

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public static LoginInfo Info
    {
        get
        {
            return SessionBll.GetLoginInfo(someInt);
        }
        set
        {
            SessionBll.UpdateLoginInfo(value, someInt);
        }
    }
}
```

and given this:

```
OtherClass.LoginInfo.Username = "BillyBob";
```

How can I call the `LoginInfo` setter when a property of `LoginInfo` changes?  I know I can do:

```
LoginInfo info = OtherClass.LoginInfo;
info.Username = "BillyBob";
OtherClass.LoginInfo = info;
```

but I want to do this without these three lines.  I want it to be automatic

Thanks

Ended up subscribing to the event in the LoginInfo class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following amendments to your class

```
public class LoginInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _userID;
    private string _UserName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return this._userID; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._userID)
            {
                this._userID = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UserID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return this._UserName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._UserName)
            {
                this._UserName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your other class you need to have a reference to the loginfo class and subscribe to the PropertyChangedEvent.

```
_privateLogInfo.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(methodToBeCalledToHandleChanges);
```

Then handle any changes in *methodToBeCalledToHandleChanges*.

Comment: currently OtherClass has only static members.  Will that be an issue?

Comment: I think it should be ok as long as the reference to the loginfo object and the method you use to handle changes are static as well.

Comment: hmm ya, the problem is that _there is no reference to the loginfo class other than the property you see in my question.  Don't think my brain is working yet...

Comment: You will need to add that yourself as I don't know how your OtherCLass is supposed to be implemented. Looking at your code, does SessionBll hold a reference to a LogInfo? if so, subscribe to the event there instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are many different approaches. The most straightforward is to have `LoginInfo` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have `OtherClass` subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event and then you can have that event handler call the setter as needed.

No matter what, you have to do some work to get this wired up correctly.

Comment: On MSDN INotifyPropertyChanged is usually referenced in the context of data binding.  Is it okay to use this in a different context?

Comment: @subt13: It's fine. Note that if makes you feel uncomfortable you could define your own interface with the same effect.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  If it's not too much trouble can you post a snippet of what the code might look like in OtherClass?